# Google Drive Api for installed application c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Can someone please show a working example code of how to use google drive api for installed application? ( access_type=offline)
I found a few explanations, but can't get to a working flow.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.daimto.com/category/googledrive/

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. I don't want the user to accept anything, actually I do not need a user at all (for the beginning), I want to be logged in always from the same account I'd opened for the app.

Comment: Then you need to look at a service account.  I don't have any pure drive examples with a service account.   The code is simpler  http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/#Google_Analytics_API_Service_Account_Authentication  not many people use Google drive with a service account because you cant see whats uploaded via the web site.

Comment: It works I have done it :)  I just don't have any tutorials on yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, What I used at least was not 'installed application', but 'web application'.
These are the steps to do:

1. Go to Google Developers Console and create a project.
2. Go to APIs & Auth
3. On APIs enable Drive API & Drive SDK.

4.On Credentials Create new Client ID for Web Application (Create your Consent screen, evev though we won't use it.)

In the Create Client ID window, add the url "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground" to the AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URIS.

5.Go to the url you added on number 4

6.Click the gear on the right and configure:

```
OAuth flow: Server-side

Access type: Offline

Use your own OAuth credentials: Tick

Then copy your Client ID & Secret from the console.
```

7.On the left, choose Drive API -> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, click Authorize APIs

8.A new window will open, asking you to accept Google OAuth... click Accept.

9.Click Exchange authorizaion code for tokens.

10.Copy & Save the Acess & Refresh tokens.

The code:

```
private static DriveService CreateServie(string applicationName)
{
  var tokenResponse = new TokenResponse
  {
    AccessToken = yourAccessToken,
    RefreshToken = yourRefreshToken,
  };

  var apiCodeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
  {
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
      ClientId = yourClientID,
      ClientSecret = yourClientSecret
    },
    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
    DataStore = new FileDataStore(applicationName)
  });

  var credential = new UserCredential(apiCodeFlow, yourEMail, tokenResponse);

  var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
  {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = applicationName
  });

  return service;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my helper class I use Kinda tweeked it for you for Google Drive.   Remember a Service account is NOT YOU.  Just because you create it does not mean that it will have access to the files on your Google drive account.  Service accounts are there own entity there own sudu user.   This creates the basic drive service that you can use to follow the other tutorials I have created that use normal Oauth2

```
/// <summary>
/// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
/// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
/// </summary>
/// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
/// <param name="keyFilePath">Location of the Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static DriveService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string keyFilePath)
{

    // check the file exists
    if (!File.Exists(keyFilePath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An Error occurred - Key file does not exist");
        return null;
    }

    string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive};     // View analytics data            

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    try
    {
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
        });
        return service;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        return null;

    }
}
```

you call it like this

```
var x = AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateServiceAccount("46123799103-6v9cj8jbub068jgmss54m9gkuk4q2qu8@developer.gserviceaccount.com",@"C:\Users\LL\Downloads\Diamto Test Everything Project-e8bf61cc9963.p12");
```

Tutorial :  [Google Drive API with Service Account C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/)

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I'm trying it, but getting an error: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"", Uri:""

Comment: Double check the service account email address and the key file location.  You need to send it the full path to the key file c:\temp\x.p12

Comment: that's my code: 
      var certificate = new X509Certificate2("D:\\Temp\\QRApp-f21b8eb0bc66.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("qrappdrive@gmail.com")
            {
              Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));


what's wrong?

Comment: qrappdrive@gmail.com <--- that's not a service account email address.  check developer console for the service account it states Email address it should end in @developer.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: ok. fixed to :       var certificate = new X509Certificate2("D:\\Temp\\QRApp-f21b8eb0bc66.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("867154538822-5ilhfkiisn4l4ggnfvukk2dvij0vib0g@developer.gserviceaccount.com ")
            {
              Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));
but it still gives the same error.